# IE images don't downscale as they do in other browsers. Why?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm in the process of a new website design.  After reading about retina displays having slightly different image requirements I was distracted by how poor Internet Explorer down-scales images compared to other browsers.

I know I must be missing something, so decided to upload an old logo I had made a few years ago for this example.  If you visit this png image http://test.glow-sticks.org/images/logo-ietest.png

If you view it at say 100%, then it looks OK in all browsers, however when you zoom out to say 25% using e.g Chrome or Firefox etc, then the image resizes nicely keeping it's smooth edges.

However when you start to zoom out using IE to say 25% or so, then the edges of the logo become jagged/pixely.

Firstly, why? And secondly, is there a simple solution to this?

I don't want to complicate the question by rambling, but I was also experimenting with SVGs.  I converted the logo to an SVG and put the image to output at 250px on the website. However on IE even if you view the page at 100% the logo is not rendering smoothly, when I get to about 300% then it starts to look good.

I know its because the images is huge to begin with, but why is it only IE to have this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Good luck if you intend to try and ensure proper rendering with zooming.  It's twitchy at best, and varies across browsers.  Why, out of curiosity, are you concerned about zooming?

Comment: I have a 15" asus laptop with native resolution of 1920 x 1080.  So because of this I have to increase the browser to 125% on ALL sites otherwise it's uncomfortable to read.  When I lower the resolution everything looks seriously horrible, not just web browsing!

But to answer your question another way, it's not so much the zooming that's the problem, if I ask IE to load an image at a reduced size than it's original size, then it looks terrible in IE even at 100% zoom.  Chrome and Firefox don't do the same. Don't you see the same in general? Take a look at test.glow-sticks.org

Comment: Fair enough - just curious.  BTW, in my IE browser, it looks fine.  Edges do not get jagged - looks really nice, actually. Maybe some browser settings I'm not aware of are causing your challenge?

Comment: Remove the "why" portion of your question, and the SVG rambling, and you'll have a better question. "Why was IE coded the way it was?" The answer is "Because." possibly with a little "Performance." and "Schedules." mixed in.

Comment: @cale_b Hmm, did you load my test site link too? test.glow-sticks.org
What resolution are you using? And which IE version? Surely if you shrink the test image which I linked to in the question to say 10% - 20% you should start to see it go jagged around the edges, whereas on other browsers it doesn't have the same result.

Comment: I did.  I shrunk / expanded it (stretching the browser to force a downsize), I did not zoom.  I did just now, though, and even at 25% it looks decent - starting to get funky, but not bad.  This is IE8 (for legacy development testing).  I haven't checked in 9+

Comment: This screen shot gives you an idea of what IE looks like compared to other browsers when the window is shrunk down (kept at 100% zoom).
The original image is the above image also in IE which is fine. http://test.glow-sticks.org/images/capture.jpg

2nd Screenshot: http://test.glow-sticks.org/images/capture2.jpg shows how I see the test website using IE with my screen using the full window at 1920 resolution (100% zoom) Can you see how bad that logo looks there?

Comment: Are you able to install IE10?  IE10 will run on Win7.  I just did a test of the `logo-ietest.png` and it looked great at 25% zoom factor, suspect the IE10 has improved image scaling algorithm over IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Thanks, but it's IE 10 that I'm using. Did you take a look at my screen captures in my previous comment? It shows exactly what I see.

Comment: Shrinking most images to 10-20% of their original size, things just ain't gonna be the same as the original hi-res.  If you don't control the graphics being displayed (i.e. you cannot make a nicer lo-res version in your favorite graphics editor), then you are totally at the mercy of the browser and whatever scaling algorithm(s) it might use for a particular version.

Comment: Fair enough, just seems a shame that IE won't do the same as the other browsers by resizing them perfectly. But understood!
What's the solution going forward for e.g my logo image?  I need the logo to be 250px for desktop viewing, but if I upload a 250px logo and view it on retina displays such as ipad then it looks blurry.  Should I be uploading double the size, e.g a 500px for retinas? Currently I've got it set as full size svg, which looks amazing on the ipad, but I think its overkill memory wise. Surely 2x is enough?

Comment: Ah, retina displays, that's a lot of pixels to wrangle in.  Almost "too many" ;-)  I think your approach sounds good, try the 2x size, see how it looks.  But the SVG sure sounds tempting, but I can't comment on the memory usage.  I'm quite interested in your solution, since I'll be soon testing some internal web apps on a retina display device (still a pending task).